# Permanova Error with adonis & ggplot2 error for metaMDS

Tags: r, ggplot2, vegan

I am trying to run a permanova on insect community composition across host plant species. No matter what we have tried, it does not work and I cannot figure out why not. I know permanova can handle zeros, but we do have a lot, could that be the issue?

We receive this error:
Error in if (any(lhs < -TOL)) stop("dissimilarities must be non-negative") :
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Here is what we tried:

```
library(vegan)

#insect community composition on 3 different species of milkweed
lilly.data<-read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lmgermeroth/Garden-sampling-SU21/main/backyard2021_main_forR.4.22.22.csv")

lilly.data$SPECIES<-as.factor(lilly.data$SPECIES)

# creating a species data matrix so I can tell the model how to calculate the community composition, but first, make them numeric.
lilly.data[6:151] <- lapply(lilly.data[6:152], as.numeric)
#Create the matrix of insect species
lilly.species<-as.matrix(lilly.data[,8:152])

lilly.dist<-vegdist(lilly.species,"bray")
#get a warning.....but it runs

lilly.permanova<-adonis2(lilly.dist ~ SPECIES,permutations=999,method='bray',data=lilly.data)
# why doesn't this work?
```

Second, we are trying to create an ordination plot, but that also won't work and we aren't sure why. Might be related to the above issue?

```
library(ggplot2)
ord<-metaMDS(lilly.species)
#this is where we throw the error....

scores<-scores(ord,display='sites')

scores<-cbind(as.data.frame(scores), Treatment=lilly.data$SPECIES)

center<-aggregate(cbind(NMDS1,NMDS2)~Treatment,data=scores,FUN=mean)

seg<-merge(scores,setNames(center,c('Species','oNMDS1','oNMDS2')),by='Treatment',sort=FALSE)

ggplot(scores,aes(x=NMDS1,y=NMDS2,colour=Treatment))+
  geom_segment(data=seg,
               mapping=aes(xend=oNMDS1,yend=oNMDS2))+
  geom_point(data=cent,size=8)+
  geom_point()+
  coord_fixed()
```

error here is:
Square root transformation
Wisconsin double standardization
Error in cmdscale(dist, k = k) : NA values not allowed in 'd'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In distfun(comm, method = distance, ...) :
you have empty rows: their dissimilarities may be meaningless in method “bray”
2: In distfun(comm, method = distance, ...) : missing values in results

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have sites where zero species were detected. After you've made your community data matrix you should remove any rows with zero species:

```
lilly.species <- lilly.species[rowSums(!lilly.species) < ncol(lilly.species), ]
```

Then all the remaining code should work fine.

Comment: That allowed me to calculate the distances but then when trying to run the permanova I get this error: Error in qr.fitted(qrhs, G) : 
  'qr' and 'y' must have the same number of rows

Comment: You need to remove the same rows from `lilly.data`, so that `lilly.species` and `lilly.data` have the same number of rows. Just repeat the above command for `lilly.data`